# C# dotnet migration nvarchar issue dotnet 2.0 not 2.0.1

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I'm currently getting an issue with mapping nvarchar / strings in dotnet. I get an error stating that I should either do .HasMaxLength() or .HasColumnType("string(10)"). I've tried both and it doesn't work. I understand this has been fixed in dotnet core 2.1, but we are half way through migrating 60% of our projects and our manager want's them all to be on the same framework / version so it's easier to update. Has anyone got any fixes for this or is my only option to update?

Just or a little bit more information, we need to inherit because we are using t4 to generate some table standard columns.

-- edit --

little more information:

```
threw exception: 
ServiceStack.WebServiceException: Data type 'nvarchar' is not supported in this form. Either specify the length explicitly in the type name, for example as 'nvarchar(16)', or remove the data type and use APIs such as HasMaxLength to allow EF choose the data type.
```

I've tried

```
builder.Property(x => x.SubBuildingName).HasColumnName("SubBuildingName").HasColumnType("nvarchar(100)");
```

and

```
builder.Property(x => x.SubBuildingName).HasColumnName("SubBuildingName").HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(100);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why the question has been voted down? the question is solid in what I'm asking and it doesn't have a duplicate in StackOverFlow... just because you don't know how to help, don't down vote the question. If your going to vote a question down at least leave some construction criticism.

Comment: Please add minimal example of how to reproduce this error and define what the error is rather than "it is not working" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Adding a minimal example is impossible or at least impracticable. Not to be snobbish or anything, but if you don't get the question you really can't help/

Comment: This should have been fixed in 2.0.1. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/releases/tag/2.0.1 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9963 If you still have problems the best place to post would be GitHub.

Comment: I did see that it was fixed, but as stated in the question we are trying to keep all the versions exactly the same. I''m more looking for a work around the problem.

Comment: That is a mistake. It is one thing to restrict yourself to major or minor release, but you should _never_ restrict yourself to a revision. A minor revision by definition contains no breaking changes, only fixes to bug and security issues, Baking in known bugs is not a safe policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table which wasn't even related to the table which was reporting the error ended up not having the .HasMaxLength(x) changed to .HasColumnType("nvarchar(x)") and that was the issue.